# Resume wget download from a different mirror

Tags: wget

I was downloading a file **bigimage.iso** from `https<nolink>://ftp.slowsite.edu/images/bigimage.iso` using the following `wget` command:

```
wget https://ftp.slowsite.edu/images/bigimage.iso
```

But, the FTP server turned out to be very slow and now I want to pause the current download and resume it from a faster mirror: `https<nolink>://ftp.fastsite.edu/images/bigimage.iso`

How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stop it (**but read all below first**) and re-download with `wget`'s `-c (--continue)`

```
wget -c https://ftp.fastsite.edu/images/bigimage.iso
```

But for testing first if it does working, do as following without interrupting already running `wget`.

1. Copy partially downloaded file `bigimage.iso` (or the file which you know its name) to separate directory. ex: `fastDIR`
2. Open Terminal and `cd fastDIR` and run the command as follows:

   ```
   wget -c https://ftp.fastsite.edu/images/bigimage.iso
   ```

   check if it does continue download or start from beginning. if it was continue you can stop previously `wget` command. otherwise don't interrupt it.

Comment: For this to work the HTTP server has to support `Range` (there are a few servers that don't).